# removeclass() and addClass() not working using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having problem with `addClass()` and `removeClass()` function in jquery. When i use the function it was replace the classes. but it was not calling the addded class functions. here is my query

HTML Code :

```
<div class="animation1 popbutton">Click Me</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(".animation1").click(function(){ 
   // my first function 
 });

$(".animation2").click(function(){ 
   // my second function 
 });
```

and my add and remove class functions are,

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'file.php',
    data : postdata,
    type : 'post',
    success : function (saveresponseText)
    {
        $(".animation1").removeClass("animation1").addClass("animation2").html("Clicked");
    } 
});
```

if click the `animation1` it will call the ajax function and it will replace the classname as `animation2` and it has some separate function. how can do this? Someone suggest a solution please.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Put your ajax code in a function and called that function inside the event.

Comment: instead use `.toggleClass(class, class2toggle)`.

Comment: $(".popbutton").removeClass("animation1").addClass("animation2").html("Clicked");

Comment: You need to attach the listener when the class is added, not before

Comment: When i see the action in console, the class name was replaced as `animation3`. but the action is not happen. It always call the  `$(".animation1").click(function(){ 
   // my first function 
 });` action only. But i need to call the second after ajax returns.

Comment: @MaTharBeevi it also call the first function only

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
$(".animation1").click(function(){ 
   // my first function 
 });
```

jQuery find the element with this class and adds a clickhandler to it. The function is not bound to the css-class.

I would suggest you either **add a clickhandler in your ajax response**, or have 2 buttons which you can hide / and show

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the event handler through document:

```
$(document).on('click','.animation2',function(){ 
   // my second function 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is that your ajax is not returning success check the console logs. actually problem was not with addClass and removeClass. see the example below.

in this example when you click on text **click me** it will call ajax request and ajax will result error so that code written in error is excecuted

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".animation1").click(function() {
    // my first function 
    clk()
  });

  $(".animation2").click(function() {
    // my second function 
  });

  function clk() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'file.php',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(saveresponseText) {},
      error: function(status) {  $(".animation1").removeClass("animation1").addClass("animation2").html("Clicked");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation1 popbutton">Click Me</div>
```